# How to install mongoose 3.6rc0

Tags: mongoose, npm

I want to try new mongoose 3.6rc0 but if I do npm install mongoose I get 3.5.7 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by running the following command:

`npm install mongoose@3.6.0rc0`

And the specified version will be installed.